# Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcdb`

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

i have recently included ExoPlayer in my project , but i am getting following error after implmenting library .

```
Error: Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcdb`.
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Type com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzf is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcdb`.
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process
```

here is my dependancy

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'ai.devsupport.instamojo:instamojolib:0.1.5'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/javaluator-3.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/PGSDK_V2.0.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-android:v1.5.8'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev63-1.22.0'
    implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.13.0'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.+'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.2.+'
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.1.jar')
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.github.iwgang:countdownview:2.1.6'
    implementation('com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.5.0')
            {
                transitive = true;
                exclude module: 'payumoney-sdk'
            }
    implementation 'com.payumoney.core:payumoney-sdk:7.5.0'
    implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.7') {
        exclude group: 'androidx.core', module: 'core'
        exclude group: 'androidx.media', module: 'media'
    }
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

project level build gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

what i have tried but got failed:
1 . i have tried to change firebase core dependency version
2 . classpath for google in project build.gradle
3 . version of exoplayer dependency
4 . i think all answer question of stack-overflow available on the web

Thank You .

Comment: 3 months later did you find a solution by chance?